# How to extract the sequence diagram from the function procedures?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, use-case-diagram

I have a E-services portal for student’s system But I'm not sure which sequence diagram will be drawn for withdrawal from the course

The student can:

- Request apology or reprieve
- Request delete or add course
- Request for re-registration
- Request withdraw from a course

Academic Advisor:

- Request Accept
- Request class expansion

Head of Department:

- Request Accept

Under of Educational Affairs:

- Request Accept

Admission and Registration:

- Request execute

Course withdrawal service procedures:

1. Transfer the application to the student's academic advisor for approval.
2. Transfer the request to the student’s head of department for approval.
3. Transfer the application to the Vice Dean for Educational Affairs for approval.
4. Automatic transfer of the application to the Deanship of Admission and Registration for implementation.

My question is:
Is the sequence diagram drawing correct for the required procedures?
How can I draw a class diagram for this system?
Is the Use case diagram correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Login` is no use case. Or do you get paid by making logins?

Comment: @bruno If nobody kicks butts nothing's gonna happen. The UML level at universities regarding UC synthesis is obviously far below zero :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the sequence diagram drawing correct for the required procedures?

First are the messages asynchronous ? The ExecutionSpecifications indicates there are not

it is not correct :

- the explicit returns everywhere indicate calls (because of the "()" ), they must be values, else there are not returns
- if the *CourseProfessor* cancel the request it is abnormal later *ExecuteRequest* was called on *AcademicAdvisor*
- While the *SubmitRequest* on *CourseProfessor* is done and return an *Accept/CancelRequest* it is not possible to have *after* the call of *ExecuteRequest* on *AcademicAdvisor*, That one must be before the return from *CourseProfessor* in the upper alternate division
- it is the same with the other cases where yuo call Accept/ExecuteRequest while the return was done so the execution finished
- the final return is illegal too, it goes to *Student* but that one does not called *ExecuteRequest* on *AdmissionAndRegistration*